# can i just optimize designated parameters in loss with tensorflow？

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I have two models in one graph,
and i need to train these two models alternately.

The loss function is like below:

```
loss = f(theta_a) * g(theta_b) 
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
     A_train_op = models[model_idx_A].optimize(loss)
```

One time I just want to optimize `theta_a` while leaving `theta_b` fixed, and the other time I want to optimize `theta_b` while leaving `theta_a` fixed.

How can I do that? 
Can `g(theta_b)` convert to some type that cannot be derived?

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer's `minimize` method has an optional parameter named `var_list`, which accepts one or more variables to optimize during training. So you can train only `theta_a` with code like this:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(loss, var_list=[theta_a])
```

Another method is to update the `TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` container of the current graph.